# With no funciona Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy utilizando with para pasar un mensaje de correcto cuando realizo un update pero no se muestra

```
 return redirect()->route('editar_usuarios','03')->with("update_correcto","CORRECTO");
```

Ruta :

```
Route::get('editar_usuarios/{dni}', [App\Http\Controllers\Usuarios\UsuariosController::class, 'show'])->name('editar_usuarios');
```

Metodo Show :

```
    public function show($dni)
{

    $usuario_editar = User::select('id','name', 'apellidos')->where("dni",$dni)->get();
    $tipos_usuarios = DB::table('tipo_usuarios')->get();

    return view("usuarios.editar_usuarios")->with("usuario_editar",$usuario_editar)->with("tipos_usuarios",$tipos_usuarios);
    

}
```

En la vista la variable siempre aparece como null :

```
@isset($update_correcto)

<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <strong>Correcto!</strong> Actualizacion correcta
</div>
@endisset
```

Porque atraves de esta linea pasos datos a las vistas :

```
return view("usuarios.editar_usuarios")
            ->with("usuario_editar",$usuario_editar)
            ->with("tipos_usuarios",$tipos_usuarios);
```

y de esta manera los recibo sin usar session :

```
@foreach ($usuario_editar as $item)
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Ocurre por que **`update_correcto`** no es una variable si no una [clave que esta vinculada con un valor en la sesión.](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data)

Lo anterior lo puedes comprobar si haces esto en tu *vista*:

```
@if(session('update_correcto'))
    {{ session()->all() }}
@endif
```

Que te debería dar una salida similar a esto:

```
array:4 [▼
  "_token" => "aqui el valor del token"
  "_previous" => array:1 [▶]
  "_flash" => array:2 [▶]
  "update_correcto" => "CORRECTO"
]
```

Entonces una vez evalúes la existencia de dicho valor lo podrás imprimir simplemente como:

```
{{ session('update_correcto') }}
```

Ahora si necesitas almacenar en la sesión mas de un valor, entonces puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
->with([
    "usuario_editar" => $usuario_editar,
    "tipos_usuarios" => $tipos_usuarios,
]);
```

Y para obtener esos valores en la vista el procedimiento inicial que te comento te servirá.

Puedes leer mas sobre [las sesiones aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#introduction)

Comment: edite la pregunta, si me puede ayudar por favor con la duda.